# How obtain value from selected tag?

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, smarty

I have different fees depending on the option selected.How obtain this value ?
Code is:

```
.................

{if $value_selected == 5}

 {$taxa_transport = 5}

{/if}
            <td>Valoare transport:</td><td>{$taxa_transport} lei</td>
....................


<select id="id_judet" onchange="getLocalitati($(this).val())">
<option value="-1">-</option>
<option value="0">Alba</option>
<option value="1">Arad</option>
<option value="2">Arges</option>
<option value="3">Bacau</option>
<option value="4">Bihor</option>
<option value="5">Bistrita-Nasaud</option>
<option value="6">Botosani</option>
<option value="7">Braila</option>
<option value="8">Brasov</option>
......................................
```

How obtain value for $value_selected?

Comment: Please translate your example into English, so that it is easily readable for everyone.

Comment: Obtain by what (in Smarty you already know value for $value_selected)? More details please.

Answer (score 2):

Inputs are client-side, so you'll need some JavaScript. I recommend using AJAX to post the value whenever the option changes:

```
$("#id_judet").change(function() {
    $.post("page.php", $(this).val(), function(data) {
        alert(data);
    });
}
```

You can post to the same page if you want, too.

HTML changes:

`<select id="id_judet" name="judet">`

Some PHP code:

```
<?php

$value_selected = $_POST["judet"];

// Do whatever calculations here

?>
```

Comment: Alba, Arad, Arges are counties and for each are different charges.Tax is {$taxa_transport}.eg.:If user selected option 0, {$taxa_transport = 10} etc

Comment: Yeah, `post` works on that. Updated my answer to include some PHP.

Comment: current page is smarty template

Comment: {$value_selected} is the search.If I know this, the problem is resolved.It can be 0,1,2,3... depending on the option selected.

Comment: In that case, you'll have to actually submit the form. As I mentioned, PHP is server-side and JavaScript is client-side, so apart from ajax and submitting forms, there's no way to communicate between the two.

Comment: I use this                                                     <script type="text/javascript">

var value = '0';

document.getElementById('id_judet').onchange = function() {
    value =  parseInt(this.value);

   alert(value);
}

</script>                                                         value returnet in alert is corect, but how transfer this in smarty to compare with another value?

Comment: As I said, you'll have to use AJAX or submit the form, but you can't submit it to the same instance.